# Accessing Data from webservices using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, web-services

I am trying to access data from a webservice using Python/Django. I am a newbie in webservices, so I was wondering if I would get any quick help pointers on what to pick. SOAP or REST.

Also, given a webservice, is there any way to know what functions it supports?

IS REST a term for accessing a webservice, read and parse the XML file?

Comment: If you mean consuming a web service, then you don't get to pick the technology — the service in question does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend [python-suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) for consuming SOAP web-services. It is very simple library and easy to get started.